# Solidifying a T-Junction

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to model the pacman maze in 3d. I'd like to use a solidify modifier so that I can easily change the thickness of all walls at the same time, however I'm having trouble with parts of the maze where the wall forms a T shape.

[image][image]

If I add subsurf modifier then the artifacts are even more obvious:

[image]

Comment: I dont think that it will be possible to do that with solidify modifier.

Comment: It will work if you separate the faces that form T-Junctions

Comment: @Denis what do you mean?

Comment: Select the faces of the short wall and hit Y button to separate

Comment: add edge split modifier before the solidify

Answer (score 2):

this method may not give you a good mesh but it looks OK :

- add a Edge split modifier before the solidify modifier
- set the solidify modifier offset to 0.0
- other modifiers are added to smooth it out

[image]

here is a cross junction :

[image]

solid view

[image]

after Bevel and Subsurf modifier :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no immediate solutions (that I can think of) to the 'variable width walls from edge-based mesh' problem, though it is interesting. There are however [Offset Scripts](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/offset_edges) that generate faces from edge-based meshes, but they don't work with the T junction, only edge-loops.

A potentially doable approach is to first make your maze shape using an edge based mesh. Then convert it to a Curve (Ctrl+C) (Curve from Mesh)

[image]

Then tweak the Bevel Depth to get the preferred thickness (radius). Then stick on a Remesh Modifier (or two - *Blocks* seems to be a good mode), but you ought to experiment which it until it comes close to what you want. If you want thinner walls you decrease the Bevel depth of the Curve, and adjust the Scale and Octree Depth in the Remesh mmodifier.

[image]

Comment: Yep remesh is the only correct way out of this, +1