# Solidify modifier creates uneven edges

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, workflow

I am creating walls for my building, the walls are made out of planes. When I add a solidify modifier to give my walls some thickness, the newly created edges aren't straight near the corners.

**Can anyone suggest possible solutions, in order to straighten out the extended edges around the corners**

*Top view below*

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29008/solidifying-a-t-junction

Comment: *Even thickness* option should works fine for the goal in the provided example. If you have a particular geometry where the method fails I would suggest to post/upload that.